# EF migrations when several developers checks in migrations at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following scenario when 2 developers are working on a project simultaniously.

I create a table, uses "add-migration, update-database". 
And #2 creates a table, uses "add-migration, update-database".

We then both check in our changes to GIT, (me first).

When I then does a update-database, I get "Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes..."

I then does "Add-Migration" and the migration created, tries to create the tables i created in the first step above. When I try to do "Update-Database" with this migration, I of course get "There is already an object named ... in the database".

The workaround I have found so far is to:

1. Update-database -TargetMigration MyLastmigration
2. Delete the migration #2 has made
3. Add-Migration theSameNameAs#2Made
4. Update-database

Am I doing something wrong? Is #2 doing something wrong? Will my workaround work for #2?

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why I don't like migrations

Comment: So this is not supposed to work?

Comment: I mean they're just a pain for this (and other) reason(s). Manage them manually. It's not that hard. For me migrations are solving a problem that doesn't exist. So I don't use them. Doesn't answer your question, just my 2 pence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can get around this problem.

1. Add a blank merge migration as follows:

   `Add-Migration Merge –IgnoreChanges`

   This command will create a new migration without any scripts but would 
   update the model snapshot to match the current model.
2. Update the model snapshot in the last migration - the approach that you have 
   mentioned, which removes the need for creating the extra blank migration 
   mentioned in option 1.

Both the above methods would work and there is nothing wrong about it. Read this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx) article for detailed explanation

Comment: That is a great article, can't believe I haven't stumbled upon it before.  Thank you for linking to it!  It explains so much about how migrations work, even in non-team environments, that just gets left out of the other migration tutorials.

Comment: That MSDN article was very usefull yes! Thanks

Comment: Dear god I have been struggling with this for so freaking long. Thank you very much.